# Is it possible to extend 'signature' of the PDA?

Tags: pda, cpi, security

Let's say, ***Program A*** calls ***Program B*** via **invoke_signed**

Is it a way for a ***Program B*** to reuse these seeds in the second layer CPI?

After experimenting a bit, I came to conclusion it cannot be achieved... Unless there is something I am missing here

Answer (score 1):

**Program B** cannot sign for any account owned by **Program A**.

However, once **Program A** signs with seeds for `account_a` in a CPI to **Program B**, **Program B** *can freely use* `account_a` *as a signer* to some **Program C**.